# How to inherit a class only if is a specific type?

Tags: c#

Suppose that I have a class called `Bot`, like this:

```
class Bot
{

}
```

now there is another class that have all the features of the `Bot`, this class is called `Tool`:

```
class Tool
{
    //some method
}
```

Now `Bot` is the only class that must be inherit the method of `Tool`. How can I constraint this like the `where` operator? Something like this:

```
class Tool where T = Bot ?
```

I don't know if is clear, but I want that only the `Bot` class can be inherit the method of `Tool`, is possible do this? Sorry for the rudimental explaination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Do you mean that only want the Tool class to be able to inherit from the Bot class and no other class?  If so, you can't do this.

Comment: Are you trying to construct a class that only a specific other class is allowed to inherit, while others can use it?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Exactly, I'm learning the `where` operator, so I want to know if a target like this is possible.

Comment: Why would you want to stop someone else from extending these classes?

Comment: @zzzzBov 'cause the features of `Tool` are only for `Bot` class.

Comment: @IlDrugo `where` is used for generic type constraints.  You are not using generics here.

Comment: If the features of `Tool` are only for the `Bot` class, then include them in the `Bot` class.

Comment: @DarrenYoung but If I create another file with `Tool` class, this class could be used for another class, so the problem is not solved completely

Comment: @IlDrugo, so lets imagine you've gotten this to work, and then decide it's a good idea to write tests for this code. You'd like to create an object that pretends to be a `Tool`, but since only `Bot` can be a `Tool` and you don't want to use an *actual* `Bot`, you can't set up these tests. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @zzzzBov Uhm yes, I think that I'll use the `partial`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible and even useless.

If you want only one class to inherit the other, why not merge them together into one class? You can also create a nested class that is only creatable from the parent class. Then you add `Tool` as a property, not a derived class.

Comment: Interesting hint, but in this case the code file will too long, or I can separate in more files?

Comment: Yes, use the `partial` keyword for that. (Read on [partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that. It sounds like you want to make `Tool` sealed, so nothing can inherit from it, but give a `Bot` a "has-a" relationship with it (not an "is-a" relationship)

In other words, a Bot should have an instance of Tool encapsulated within it, not inherit from it.